# Database_Id for our database in sys.databases does not match that of DB_ID ( '<our database' )

Tags: azure-sql-database

The Database ID in sysdatabases and sys.databases for our database is 4.

The function DB_ID ( '<our database>' ) returns 5 for our database. 
Also any missing index data for our database in the table sys.dm_db_missing_index_details is assigned to database_id 5 also.

It seems to me that the sys.databases should have ID 5 and *NOT* 4. This is driving me bonkers and making it so sp_BlitzIndex does not work.

Does anyone know why my database id doesn't match between sys.databases, sys.dm_db_missing_index_details and DB_ID() on SQL Azure? Is it actually screwed up or does this just work different in SQL Azure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure SQL DB is different !

The `database_id` column from `sys.databases` (dont use `sysdatabases` <-- its deprecated) will remain the same for the database.

The [`DB_ID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx) is a function and the value will change if the Azure DB is failed over.

Best is to use `name` <-- database name column.

People have reported that [here](http://www.sqlindepth.com/2016/05/inconsistent-database-ids-in-sql-azure-v12/) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20791489-fad8-4469-98f5-1749d9450949/database-id-gets-changed?forum=ssdsgetstarted).

> One shouldn't rely on database id / db_id builtin in azure as **it changes whenever database moves to a different sql instance (because of the database failover)**. Use name instead of the id. Also please note that the db_id can potentially be different than in the sys.databases